# Is there a link that I can use to link fitbit to pc

Tags: error-handling

I want to link a fitbit to my PC but I cannot down load the software off the fitbit website as its says its not compaptable with Ubuntu

Comment: http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/syncing-fitbit-from-ubuntu/1651

Answer (score 0):

Ignore any compatibility messages and download it anyway.
Download this software: [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

After you do, it should allow you to run .exe files like you ran windows. Run the installer normally. Make sure to create a shortcut on the desktop, it'll make your life easier. Open the software and it should work.